# How to delete Tester's Name from MTM 2013 while it is not showing after opening test case

Tags: testing, ui-automation, microsoft-test-manager

**In image 1** :- It shows that name of Tester is visible.

**In image 2** :- After opening image name of Tester is not visible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't see your first image, I'll try to guess.

I assume you assign testers in test suite by clicking the button "Assign". Then the name of tester appears in the column "Testers". This assignment is different from the one you show in the image 2. This assignment is related to **Test Run**, and the one you show in test case from the image 2 is related to **Test Case** itself.

Basically, from test suite with "Assign" button you assign testers who will execute the particular test scenario. Their name will appear in test results and you can obtain who did what part by opening "Results" tab and sorting diagrams by name. **After you assign this field, it cannot be empty. When you add the test case to another test plan, then this field will be again empty in new test plan.**

An assignment in Test Case shows who is responsible for the test scenario, who writes and maintains it. So, these are to different instances.